# Bootstrap responsive layout in mobile convert to tabs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

So as the title suggests, I am currently using Bootstrap.  I am working on a responsive layout that in desktop size, is just a normal columned floated layout.  Then in mobile device or tablet size, it adds bootstrap tabs.  I am not sure quite how to solve this as the bootstrap 3 col-xs floats don't seem to be playing nice with the tabs plugin.  I have made a diagram to help explain.

[image: Layout Diagram]

Fiddle I've been working with [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wNZc6/)

```
<div class="container">   
<div class="content">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs visible-phone">
        <li class="active"><a href="#t1" data-toggle="tab">T1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#t2" data-toggle="tab">T2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#t3" data-toggle="tab">T3</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="row tab-content">
        <div class="col-sm-4 tab-pane active" id="enter">
            <div class="inner-right-border">
                <h2>T1 CONTENT</h2>
                <hr />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="tab-pane" id="t2">
                <h2>T2 CONTENT</h2><hr />
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="t3">
                <h2>T3 CONTENT</h2><hr />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What do you want it to do? What is the problem? Where is your markup?

Comment: Sorry about that forgot to post it!

Comment: Did you ever manage to make this work?

Answer (score 12):

Needed something similar

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- Nav tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs device-small" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active col col-xs-12 col-sm-4" id="home">...home...</div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane col-xs-12 col-sm-4" id="profile">...profile...</div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane col-xs-12 col-sm-4" id="messages">...messages...</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* small device */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .device-big {
        display: none;
    }
    .device-small {
        display: block;
    }
}
/* big device */
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
    .device-big, .tab-content > .tab-pane {
        display: block;
    }
    .device-small {
        display: none;
    }
    .tab-content > .tab-pane {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Here is working example: http://jsfiddle.net/bomff3g6/

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Thank you :) I really need that + works perfectly [upvoted]

Answer (score 1):

The CSS code above works, but has an issue with nested tabs. e.g from the initial - future tab one then contains 2 tabs.

I wanted to post this as a comment to the Atul's response, but don't have enough "reputation" points.

This is a slight tweak to allow nested tabs.

```css
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .device-big {
    display: none;
  }
  .device-small {
    display: block;
  }
}
/* big device */
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
  .tab-content > .tab-pane.device-big {
    display: block;
  }
  .device-small {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/41s795qn/

A updated bootstrap v4 version from Atul Yadav's answer:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Nav tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs hidden-md-up" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="#home" aria-controls="home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content row">
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active col col-12 col-md-4" id="home">...home...</div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane col-12 col-md-4" id="profile">...profile...</div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane col-12 col-md-4" id="messages">...messages...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* big device */
@media(min-width : 768px) {
    .tab-content > .tab-pane {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Comment: For the stable release of bootstrap 4 hidden-md-up has to be changed to: d-md-none

Answer (score 0):

The tab plugin doesn't work properly with the column classes of bootstrap. You may use the column classes on desktop, with the tab component hidden using media queries on desktop. Then display the tabs and hide the columns on mobile.